# Unable to sort PLP with Configurable products based on discount (special_price)

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, category-listing, product-sorting, product-listing

I have configurable products in my PLP and I want to sort with "special_price" attribute.

I edited the special_price attribute from admin and allowed it to be sortable in storefront.
But I am facing issue that it is working only for simple products and not for the Configurable products.

Also I can see an open issue on github similar to this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15609

Has anyone also ran into the same anytime, if so please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer below link for your issue.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.2/ee/user_guide/catalog/category-products-sort.html